# Multithreading in JAXRS server side implementation

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a web service that is taking a long time to process a request. The majority of the time is spent while converting the SQL ResultSet to java objects. I am planning to move the heavy work (calling the DB and converting the ResultSet into java objects)into a new thread. I haven't done any multi-threading in services before. I am curious to know if this will cause any problems when the service is deployed and serving multiple requests. Will there be any deadlock or other threading issues?

To provide more context, the service returns all the active orders for the given date range. When the query qualifies for large data (~300k rows), the service is slowing down. We ruled out the option to implement pagination because our use case requires all the active orders to be returned with one call. I tried looking into leveraging Jersey's @ManagedAsync but we can't uplift to jersey 3.x at this point. Any other recommendations that I should look into?

Comment: @ManagedAsync is supported in 2.x. See also https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10146

Comment: Thanks for the link. After going through the link, I feel like using ManagedAsync will also not help with the request processing time perceived by the client. Statement from the link -" Note that the use of server-side asynchronous processing model will not improve the request processing time perceived by the client." 

Based on the above statements, I feel like I should rule out using ManagedAsync

Comment: Yea that's not really the point of the asynchronous processing. It's just mean to free up resources for long running requests.

Comment: You can send the response in chunks (as they are retrieved) so the client can start processing them as they are received. Look at the chucked output section in that same link